# liquibase diffChangeLog not generating snowflake Views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, liquibase

Using the community edition of Liquibase for our snowflake instances.

Running the diffChangeLog command generates a script with only Tables listed. Stored Procedures and Views are totally ignored.

Surely this isn't right.

As per the section "Output" near the bottom of this page: https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/diffchangelog.html  it states:
The diffChangeLog command produces a list of all Objects and creates a changelog with a list of changesets.

Liquibase Community diffChangeLog categories:

Catalog
Column
Foreign Key
Index
Primary Key
Schema
Sequence
Procedure
Unique Constraints
View

Is there a bug?

I've downloaded and copied the latest jar files (liquibase-snowflake-4.4.1 and snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2).

Answer (score 0):

This is because Snowflake database does not fully support all the liquibase commands.

If you see the note below, it says: `Note: Not all database platforms support all stored logic types that are listed.` and Snowflake is one of them.